# Use ffprobe on Sagemaker Jupyter Notebook: /bin/sh: 1: ffprobe: not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, ffprobe

I need to use `FFprobe` to get the metadata(the orientation of the video) of videos on SageMaker Studio. Even I installed `FFmpeg` and `FFprobe` via `pip install`, the notebook doesn't recognize the packages.

`/bin/sh: 1: ffprobe: not found`

It is tricky since I've already tried to install them on System terminal and it worked, but it still doesn't work on the Image terminal or Jupyter Notebook.

Is that because of the dependencies? I've checked other ways to get the metadata but couldn't find one working. I could get simple metadata via `hachoir-metadata` but it didn't give the orientation. Any advice is welcomed. Thanks.